# Autoref after putting the same counter for all environments

Tags: xetex, hyperref, environments, autoref

I have a xelatex amsart document in which I defined first a counter

```
\newcounter{thms}
```

and then defined environments,

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thms}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defni}[thms]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thms]{Lemma}
```

However, I also want to change the names of their autorefs

```
\newcommand{\lemautorefname}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{theorem}
```

but when I try autoreffing I get that both lemmas and theorems are named 'theorem 1.X'. Do you have an idea how to solve this so lemmas will be named in their names and theorems in their autoreffed name?

**EDIT:** MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,,usenames,dvipsnames]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\date{\today}
\theoremstyle{remark}

\newcounter{thms}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newcommand{\lemautorefname}{lemma}
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{theorem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{thm}\label{stupid}
My first theorem is stupid
\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{stupid2}
Also silly
\end{lem}
Both \autoref{stupid} and \autoref{stupid2} are silly. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: @campa I edited the question.

Comment: Isn't using `cleveref` easier?

Comment: @egreg Maybe it is but I have already written 50 pages with 'hyperref' so probably I missed the train.

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov Changing `\autoref` into `\cref` doesn't seem a big deal.

Comment: @egreg I included `\usepackage{cleveref}` in the preamble and then replaced `\autoref` by `cref` and then instead of the same environment name I get a pair of questions marks in both cases.

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov `\usepackage{cleveref}` must be *after* `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @egreg it is. Otherwise I don't think it could have been compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `aliascnt`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{aliascnt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newaliascnt{lem}{thm}
\newtheorem{lem}[lem]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lem}

\newcommand{\lemautorefname}{lemma}
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{thm}\label{stupid}
My first theorem is stupid
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{stupid2}
Also silly
\end{lem}

Both \autoref{stupid} and \autoref{stupid2} are silly. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `cleveref`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <---- don't use this with XeLaTeX
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{thm}\label{stupid}
My first theorem is stupid
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{stupid2}
Also silly
\end{lem}

Both \cref{stupid} and \cref{stupid2} are silly. 

\end{document}
```

[image]